# Windows Forms C# - Recuperar info de un formulario en otro

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo dos winforms, en el form1 ingreso información y llamo al form2 con Showdialog para que se agregue información complementaria.

En el form2 hay un botón para grabar el cual guarda la información de los dos formularios.

Una vez grabado se cierra el form2 y se queda abierto el form1, lo que necesito es que de alguna forma el form1 sepa que se guardó correctamente la info para que se bloqueen los controles ya que pueda darse el caso de que el usuario no presionó el botón grabar sino que cerró el form2 para modificar algun dato del form1, en este caso no debo bloquear los controles en el form1 .

Espero haberme explicado xD,gracias de antemano.

Saludos,

Comment: podes usar un evento.. podes dejar una variable en el form2 antes que se cierre y fijarte como quedo.. un form es una clase como cualquier otra. Esta pregunta ya esta en el sitio (y no la estoy encontrando)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar esto en el formulario 1 (Ventana1) crea una variable o un campo, en mi caso creo un label, luego tienes que crear un método editarRespuesta() que es que recibirá o editara este valor, el método tiene que ser público.
Ahora cuando habrás el segundo formulario (Ventana2), al instanciar el formulario 2, le envías como parámetro todo el formulario 1 (puedes enviar como 'this'), en el formulario dos, ya podrás acceder al método para editar el campo respuesta(lblRespuesta) con el valor que eligió en el dialogo, ten un buen día.
A continuación el código

Formulario 1 (Ventana1.cs)

```
public partial class Ventana1 : Form
    {
        public Ventana1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.btnUno.Click += BtnUno_Click;
        }

        private void BtnUno_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ventana2 v2 = new Ventana2(this);
            v2.Show();
        }

        public void editarRespuesta(string resp)
        {
            this.lblRespuesta.Text = resp;
        }

    }
```

Formulario 2 (Ventana2.cs)

```
public partial class Ventana2 : Form
    {
        Ventana1 ventana1;
        public Ventana2(Ventana1 v1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.btnGuardar.Click += BtnGuardar_Click;
            ventana1 = v1;
            
        }

        private void BtnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string mensaje = "¿Quieres guardar los datos ingresados?";

            string titulo = "GUARDAR";

            MessageBoxButtons botones = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;

            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(mensaje,titulo,botones);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                ventana1.editarRespuesta("Elemento guardado");
            }
            else
            {
                ventana1.editarRespuesta("No se guardo información");
            }

        }
    }
```

Imagen formulario 1

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso, en el que sólo quieres saber si se pulsó el botón `Aceptar` o `Grabar`, puedes utilizar la propiedad `DialogResult` del segundo formulario:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0